# Access SQL Server based Winform application from another computer through LAN (SQL Auth)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

> **I am trying to run my SQL Server based Winform application from two computers which are connected in LAN.(Desktop PC, Laptop)**

I followed MSDN and the below mentioned StackOverflow answers:

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715440/how-to-run-desktop-application-using-sql-server-database-on-other-computer-conne) (Verified Answer)

[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486610/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-another-computer) (dyslexicanaboko's Answer)

I tried the below steps:

**My Winform app's connection string:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WinFormMetroTest.Properties.Settings.SampleDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.6\SAINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;User Id=sa;Password=bpmadmin1;Integrated Security=False;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

> **In my Laptop:**

- I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition, Windows 7 64bit Ultimate.
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, I enabled the protocol for TCP/IP for my instance "SAINSTANCE" and in the IP addresses, I specified TCP port as 1433 for all IPs. In IP4, I mentioned my Laptop's IP `192.168.1.6` and restarted SQL Server Instance and SQL Server Agent.
- In Firewall setting, `Inbound Rules` - Specified TCP port as 1433

And finally I run my application in my **Laptop**, it gets connected to my DB and works perfectly.

> **In my Desktop PC:**

- I have Windows 64 bit Ultimate. I **do not have** SQL Server 2008 R2 or any other version here.
- In Firewall setting, `Inbound Rules` - Specified TCP port as 1433
  and also UDP port as 1434
  `Outbout Rules` - Specified TCP port as 1433 and also UDP port as 1434

Now I ran my application in Desktop PC and it shows connection error.
I also disabled firewall completely in my Desktop PC and tried, it doesn't connect and shows the same error.

Please tell if I went wrong in any steps which I referred or provide possible fix for this.

Please comment if you require any further details about this issue.