# How to make wpf apps on same netwrok read data from one SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, networking

I have a C# WPF app running inside Visual Studio 2017 on my computer and I am using SQL Server 2014 to save/select data.

How can I run it on another Windows computer on the same network without installing Visual Studio / SQL Server? This app should read/insert data from/in my SQL Server.

I tried to using publish option, but the app isn't able to read data from my computer on other network pcs.

Also, I tried to copy bin to other pcs, but the app still isn't able to read data from SQL Server.

I already prepare SQL Server to receive a connection using the following steps on the following link:

[How to run desktop application using SQL Server database on other computer connected with LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715440/how-to-run-desktop-application-using-sql-server-database-on-other-computer-conne)

Also in `app.config`, I found the following connection string:

```
  connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-QO2VUSP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AJFactory;Integrated Security=True"
```

I Checked the Event handler from other pcs, I find the following Errors:

> Application: Factory App.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.Object, System.String,
>   System.Security.SecureString, Boolean,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.String, Boolean,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager

And the following:

> Faulting application name: Factory App.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5bdb0efa Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.17134.319, time stamp: 0x5ea0e53d Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x001117d2

Comment: Do the other computers have access to your SQL Server?

Comment: @PaulKaram i am checking that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `Integrated Security=False` then When it false,you need to specified the `User ID` and `Password` in the connections string, For more info about Integrated Security, Check the following Answer:

[What is the difference between Integrated Security = True and Integrated Security = SSPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229691/what-is-the-difference-between-integrated-security-true-and-integrated-securit)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a WPF application is irrelevant.

You need to change the connection string for your SqlConnection object. It will probably say something like "Data Source=Localhost" or "Data Source=127.0.0.1". This should be changed to the network name of your PC.

You will also need to check your Sql Server / Database configuration that another user has the correct access rights that this application needs.

Comment: how ican chagne datasource if i am copy the exe to other pcs ?

Comment: @MikeDarwish It will be somewhere in your source code - ideally in an separate file from the application .exe e.g. App.config

Comment: on App.config i found the following   connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-QO2VUSP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AJFactory;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: I take care of all your points, maybe we missing something – Mike Darwish 3 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of security type in the connection string you have:

```
Integrated Security=True
```

works only if the two computers are in the same domain. I advise you to add UserName and Password for SQL in connectionString