# How can I connect to SQL Server on another machine

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have problem when connecting to the database when I install my program on another machine.

In my program, I connect database with this connection string:

```
@"Data Source=Lee-PC;Initial Catalog=CoffeeManagement;Integrated Security=True";
```

I realize that on another PC, it will not be `Lee-PC` for data source, and I can't connect to SQL Server with that link. Please help me know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up below threads
[How to run desktop application using SQL Server database on other computer connected with LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715440/how-to-run-desktop-application-using-sql-server-database-on-other-computer-conne)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's not solve my problem. I create database on user's machine .And when I run my program on that machine. It will connect on user's database. That maybe JOHN-PC not Lee-PC

Comment: @NgoHoang, you can specify "." instead of "JOHN-PC" or "Lee-PC" to connect to the local default instance.

Comment: @DanGuzman It's work for me. Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't provide link only answers. Answers should be stand alone only using links for reference.